# Using Form.Select from React Semantic UI with React-hooks

Tags: react-hooks, semantic-ui-react

as the question suggests, I'm using RSUI with React-Hooks in a Next.js project and I'm trying to figure out how to send a payload from a Form.Select to a graphql endpoint. I've included a lot of extra code for context but really what I'm after is to successfully set "security_type" using setValues

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Segment, Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import Loading from '../../components/loading'
import Error from '../../components/error'
import { useFetchUser } from '../../lib/user'
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import query from '../../graphql/project/query';
import mutation from '../../graphql/project/mutation';


const security_types = [
  { key: 'Bank Guarantee', value: 'Bank Guarantee', text: 'Bank Guarantee', name: 'Bank Guarantee' },
  { key: 'Cash Retention', value: 'Cash Retention', text: 'Cash Retention', name: 'Cash Retention' },
  { key: 'Surety Bond', value: 'Surety Bond', text: 'Surety Bond', name: 'Surety Bond' },
];

function CreateProject() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query);
  const [createProject] = useMutation(mutation,
    {
      onCompleted(data) {
        Router.replace("/create_project", "/project/" + data.createProject.project_id, { shallow: true });
      }
    });
  const { user, user_loading } = useFetchUser()

  let [form, setValues] = useState({
    project_number: '',
    project_name: '',
    security_type: '',
  });

  let updateField = e => {
    console.log('e: ', e)
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  let mutationData = ''

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) return <Error />;
  return (
    <Layout user={user} user_loading={user_loading}>
      <h1>Let's create a project</h1>
      {user_loading ? <>Loading...</> :
        <div>
          <Segment>
            <Form
              onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('form: ', form)
                createProject({ variables: { ...form } });
                form = '';
              }}>
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                label='Project Number'
                name="project_number"
                value={form.project_number}
                placeholder="Project Number"
                onChange={updateField}
              />
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                label='Project Name'
                name="project_name"
                value={form.project_name}
                onChange={updateField}
              />
              <Form.Select
                fluid
                selection
                label='Security Type'
                options={security_types}
                placeholder='Security Type'
                name="security_type"
                value={form.security_type}
                onChange={(e, { value }) => setValues(console.log('value: ', value), { "security_type": value })}
              />
              <Button>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
          </Segment>
        </div>
      }
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default CreateProject;
```

I think all my troubles relate to the `onChange` section so any help would be great.

Comment: should work, can you give us a codesandbox that reproduces the problem? can you give more details about what the console logs are?

Comment: I would also seperate the useState(object) to a few separate useState (one for each field)